# GeoJson based on shapefile : large coordinates

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, geojson, ogr2ogr

I'm quite new to GeoJson (for use with d3), and in need of some help. When I convert my available shapefile (.shp) with ogr2ogr to a GeoJson-file, the resulting coordinates are very big numbers (in the range of 100000.000).

The shapefile is accompanied by a .prj file which states the following :

> PROJCS["PCS_CarMAGBOG",GEOGCS["GCS_CarMAGBOG",DATUM["CGS_CarMAGBOG",SPHEROID["GRS80 Mod",6380687.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",92334.879],PARAMETER["False_Northing",109320.965],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-74.14659167],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",4.680486111],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

How do I reverse-engineer this in order to get true latitude and longitude ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need any reverse engineering. ogr2ogr is able to read the projection information from prj file for you.

Just execute:

```
ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f geoJSON -lco COORDINATE_PRECISION=7 future.geojson your_shapefile.shp
```

Comment: Incredibly powerful.